# iOS: does a basic blockchain implementation fall under "exempt encryption"

Tags: ios, encryption, app-store-connect, blockchain

Did anyone figure out whether a basic blockchain implementation falls under "exempt encryption" as described in iTunesConnect if implemented purely by standard iOS means and/or by using CryptoSwift or IBM BlueCryptor?

By basic implementation I mean two things:

- cryptographic hash (link to previous block and payload as Merkle tree)
- asymmetric encryption (protection of private data in blockchain entries and signature purpose)